# Errata notification activity

Tags: android

I've 2 notifications that starts with alarm manager. Runs perfectly but I've a problem: when the first notification is active (in notification bar) if I don't click on it, and second notifications start, I see new notification, but if I click the new activity show first notification.

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
CharSequence tickerText = not1[x];
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

CharSequence contentTitle = "title";
CharSequence contentText = not1[x];

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza", null, context, Notify.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("notify", not1[x]);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

final int HELLO_ID = 1;

mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

Comment: so what's the question? You want both of them to stay there till you click on them or the latest one to act correctly?

Comment: I'd like, when the next notification starts (and I see it on notification bar) I click on notification and new that notification in activity (and not the previous one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following Flag to your Pending Intent,  `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`

Something like this,

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context,1, IntentObj, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

In your code,

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```